# What images are generally available for use in MWEs?

Tags: graphics, mwe

In preparing an MWE it is often useful to include some kind of graphic image. In a simple case this can be done via

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
THIS IS AN IMAGE
\caption{An image}
\end{figure}
```

But sometimes a more evocative image is useful, or one that is not enclosed in an environment. There are some images generally available for such purposes, particularly provided by the `mwe` and various `tikz...` packages. Also one from `pstricks`. Are there others?

Here is a short example of some of these.

```
% images.tex  What images does ``everyone'' have?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\usepackage{tikzlings-cats}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\section{From MWE package}

\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{MWE example-image}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{MWE example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption{MWE example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\caption{MWE example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-16x10}
\caption{MWE example-image-16x10}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-10x16}
\caption{MWE example-image-10x16}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-16x9}
\caption{MWE example-image-16x9}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-9x16}
\caption{MWE example-image-9x16}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-golden}
\caption{MWE example-image-golden}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-golden-upright}
\caption{MWE example-image-golden-upright}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-1x1}
\caption{MWE example-image-1x1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-plain}
\caption{MWE example-image-plain}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-empty}
\caption{MWE example-image-empty}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100bp}
\caption{MWE example-grid-100x100bp}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}
\caption{MWE example-grid-100x100tp}
\end{figure}

%\end{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-golden}
\caption{MWE example-image-golden}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{MWE example-image-duck}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{From pstricks}

\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/images/tiger}
\caption{pstricks/images/tiger}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{From tikzpicture package}

\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \duck
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{TIKZDUCKS duck}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \duck[water=cyan!50!blue]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{TIKZDUCKS duck[water]}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\section{From tikzmarmot package}

\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \marmot[3D]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{TIKZMARMOT marmot[3D]}
\end{figure}


\clearpage

\section{From tikzlings package}

\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \cat
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{TIKZLINGS-CAT cat}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

At one point I felt that I had an image of a frog but it seems to have faded into the background. What have I missed out?

Comment: You only need to include the `graphicx` package.

Comment: You only need to load `tikzlings` to have `\marmot` and `\cat` available. As for the frog, maybe this was from the `frogbox` from p. 74 of the `tcolorbox` manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include any image that's in the default  input path. If you restrict to PNG files just to be definite,

```
$ grep '\.png'  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/ls-R  | wc -l
1437
```

which is rather too many to list here. Also some will be in the doc tree

If you restrict to the tex tree then

```
$ find  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex -name '*.png' | wc -l
76
```

or the full list

```
find  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex -name '*.png' | sed -e 's@.*/@@'
context-version.png
mill.png
alertmessage-error.png
alertmessage-info.png
alertmessage-success.png
alertmessage-warning.png
lNPBT_SC_linie.png
NPBT_eufom_backgound.png
NPBT_eufom_frametitlebackgound.png
NPBT_eufom_linie.png
NPBT_eufom_logo.png
NPBT_FOM_background.png
NPBT_FOM_frametitlebackground.png
NPBT_FOM_ifes_backgound.png
NPBT_FOM_ifes_frametitlebackgound.png
NPBT_FOM_ifes_logo.png
NPBT_SC_logo.png
ghsystem_acid-8.png
ghsystem_acid.png
ghsystem_aqpol.png
ghsystem_bottle-2-black.png
ghsystem_bottle-2-white.png
ghsystem_bottle.png
ghsystem_exclam.png
ghsystem_explos-1.png
ghsystem_explos-2.png
ghsystem_explos-3.png
ghsystem_explos-4.png
ghsystem_explos-5.png
ghsystem_explos-6.png
ghsystem_explos.png
ghsystem_flame-2-black.png
ghsystem_flame-2-white.png
ghsystem_flame-3-black.png
ghsystem_flame-3-white.png
ghsystem_flame-4-1.png
ghsystem_flame-4-2.png
ghsystem_flame-4-3-black.png
ghsystem_flame-4-3-white.png
ghsystem_flame-5-2-black.png
ghsystem_flame-5-2-white.png
ghsystem_flame-O-5-1.png
ghsystem_flame-O.png
ghsystem_flame.png
ghsystem_health.png
ghsystem_skull-2.png
ghsystem_skull-6.png
ghsystem_skull.png
ijsra_logo.png
dhbw-logo.png
lwarp_baseline_marker.png
example-grid-100x100bp.png
example-grid-100x100pt.png
example-image-10x16.png
example-image-16x10.png
example-image-16x9.png
example-image-1x1.png
example-image-4x3.png
example-image-9x16.png
example-image-a.png
example-image-b.png
example-image-c.png
example-image.png
hand.png
info.png
warn.png
cc-by-sa.png
cc_somerights.png
dangerous-bend.png
jacobs-logo.png
shading-l2r.png
blueshade.png
crinklepaper.png
goldshade.png
pink_marble.png
UoWlogo.png
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about some Linux facilities that I'm sure I used to know. I'm surprised that there are so many images available but unfortunately most to me seem pretty dull for generic use; `mill.png` being an exception. I think that, if I need to, I will stick to the `mwe` package offerings. It would be nice if the `pstricks` `tiger.pdf` could be generally available as it has that *wow* factor.