# How to make custom sizes for example images?

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I found this very post on available example images [What images are generally available for use in MWEs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539165/what-images-are-generally-available-for-use-in-mwes) , but could not find the size I need.  I am looking for a wide-aspect image that matches the size of a teaser figure (e.g. ACM sigconf) which would be around 16x3. The aspect ratios I could find were:

```
example-image-10x16.png
example-image-16x10.png
example-image-16x9.png
example-image-1x1.png
example-image-4x3.png
example-image-9x16.png
```

Is there a way to generate a wider one?

p.s. I am using overleaf, so some of the commands like searching through what is available to me is not so convenient, so I apologize if it is in that list of 1400 images.

Comment: Normally it isn't good practice, but for the purpose of an example image, you could take one of the existing ones and distort its aspect ratio `\includegraphics[width=16cm,height=3cm]{example-image-duck}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to use an example image with a specific size to print one on a document, because you can always specify the width and height of an image you include with `\includegraphics`. Of course, the "Image" text will be distorted, but that doesn't really matter for an example image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.1875\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you and good point that the distortion is fine.